# Error uploading new template in extension manager in joomla

Tags: joomla

Getting the following error:
Error
There was an error uploading this file to the server.
Maximum PHP file upload size is too small: This is set in php.ini in both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings of your PHP settings (located in php.ini and/or .htaccess file).

Unable to find install package

I have open the ini file but didnt find any size options in this file

Comment: It seems strange since templates should not be that big.  Assuming you got this template from the original maker (so you know it isn't huge because it's loaded with malware from a site that is giving you free downloads of commercial templates) you might want to ask the template designer what approach to take.  However you could also use ftp to put the files (unzipped) into the tmp directory and do install from directory.

Comment: @Elin - A lot of servers by default have a max upload limit of 2mb, which some template zips can be, especially if they contain lots of assets and template overrides.

Comment: Sure, that's why discover install in particular was created.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the php.ini of the apache server or watever you are using.

add the following lines in it.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

You can view it in phpinfo or in global configuration of joomla PHP settings.